reverse_copy c++ no funciona
estoy haciendo un programa en el que tengo que copiar el contenido de un vector dentro de otro pero en orden inverso. Estoy utilizando reverse_copy pero cuando lo imprimo sale en el orden normal
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void palindrome (int num){
    std::vector <int> vec_num;
    vec_num.push_back(num);
    std::vector <int> vec_num_reves(vec_num.size());
    for(int i = 0; i < vec_num.size(); i++){
        std::cout << vec_num[i] << std::endl;
    }
    std::reverse_copy(std::rbegin(vec_num), std::rend(vec_num), std::begin(vec_num_reves));
    for(const auto& element: vec_num_reves){
        std::cout << element << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    palindrome(125);
    return 0;
}


Claro que obtienes el mismo resultado, si tu vector solo tiene un elemento, se verá igual que con el orden inverso.
Además, con rbegin obtienes un iterador desde el último elemento al primero. reverse_copy copia los elementos en orden inverso. Ambos sirven para invertir el orden. Así que si los usas juntos obtienes el orden original. Es como multiplicar 2 veces por -1.
Este es el ejemplo que puedes encontrar en la documentación:
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
 
int main()
{
    auto print = [](const std::vector<int>& v)
    {
        for (const auto& value : v)
            std::cout << value << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    };
 
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
    print(v);
 
    std::vector<int> destination(3);
    std::reverse_copy(std::begin(v), std::end(v), std::begin(destination));
    print(destination);
 
    std::reverse_copy(std::rbegin(v), std::rend(v), std::begin(destination));
    print(destination);
}

Salida:
1 2 3 
3 2 1 
1 2 3


Es mas.. mirando la docu, ves que la funcion simplemente hace un for inverso.. casi que llamar a la funcion es un sinsentido...

Gracias, pero entonces qué es lo que le está sobrando a mi código?

@r_card repito lo que dije en la respuesta: usar rbegin y reverse_copy es como multiplicar 2 veces por -1. Con el ejemplo te debería quedar claro. Lo que funciona como quieres es std::reverse_copy(std::begin(v), std::end(v), std::begin(destination));
